# Compare two strings (but different types of)

Tags: c++, string, command-line-arguments, string-comparison

In a C++ program, I need to compare if 2 strings are equals or not :

```
TagLib::String artist1 = f.tag()->artist();
```

(see http://taglib.github.io/api/classTagLib_1_1String.html)

and

```
argv[2]
```

(which comes from  `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`).

I tried lots of ways to do it, but I don't succeed :
`artist1 != argv[2]` doesn't work, `strcmp(artist1,argv[2])` doesn't work as well, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
 artist1.to8Bit() != argv[2]
```

According to the documentation, function [`to8Bit()`](http://taglib.github.io/api/classTagLib_1_1String.html#afcb8da05f81a6ab30a0ef3eccbab4a65) should return an object of type `std::string()`, for which an overload of `operator !=` accepting a `const char*` is available.

Just make sure you include the appropriate header before:

```
 #include <string> // <== YOU WILL NEED THIS TO WORK WITH std::string
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the reference link you provided, `TagLib::String` only provides comparison operators for other `TagLib::String`s. A constructor based on C-style strings is provided too:

```
TagLib::String (const char *s, Type t=Latin1)
```

You can compare a TagLib::String with a C-style char* by first constructing a `TagLib::String` from the `char*`:

```
if(artist1 != TagLib::String(argv[2])) ...
```